# Why is the $R^2$ for fitting y(x) the same as for fitting x(y)?

Tags: least-squares, r-squared

Suppose I have some samples for $x, y \in R$ and I fit two linear least squares models: $y = a x + b$ and $x = c y + d$.

The two lines of best fit found in this way will generally be different.

It seems, however, that the $R^2$ for these two models will always be the same. I couldn't see why this should be from the definition of $R^2$. Is it obvious for some reason?

Answer (score 6):

The coefficient of determination $R^2$ is formally defined as
$$1 - \dfrac{\text{Sums of Squares of Residuals}}{\text{Sums of Squares Total}}.$$

It is also known that for simple regression (only one predictor), $R^2$ is also the [square of the correlation between $x$ and $y$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient). Since the $Corr(X,Y) = Corr(Y,X)$, the $R^2$ will be the same for the regression of $X$ on $Y$ and the regression of $Y$ on $X$.

Note that other properties of the correlation will also be inherited by $R^2$. For example, if you change the units of $X$ or $Y$, the $R^2$ will not change.

Answer (score 1):

@Greenparker gave you a good answer with a formula.

On a more intuitive level, simple linear regression fits a line on a plane designed to minimize the distance between the points and the line. That distance doesn't change if you flip x and y axes.

(Again, that's just for intuition).

Comment: But that's the weird thing to me---when you fit x(y) instead of y(x), the line of fit in the x-y plane _does_ change, as do all the distances of points to it. Yet overall R^2 apparently does not?